# How to use window.location = "http://{remote_url}" in Android Cordova v4.0.2?

Tags: android, cordova

In Cordova's 3.6.4 I was able to perform window.location = "http://somepage.com" to load a dynamic page inside the root/main webview.

Now in version 4.0.2, when I try to redirect the user through `window.location` or `window.location.href`  `= "http://destination.com"`  i get this popup to pick an app to launch the URL.

The most curious part is that Cordova iOS works just fine

[image]
Is there a reason for this?

Comment: You shouldn't use window.location to redirect to a remote site in first place. Are you sure this doesn't happen if you downgrade the cordova version?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure because i was using this approach to run multiple apps withing a single app. Also, i you try using window.location to a remote address from iOS cordova you will that it still works

Comment: iOS works in a different way

Comment: Okay, after digging I'm getting closer to the solution. The problem is being caused by some of the plugins installed into the app. I'm trying one by one to detect which one is cause

Comment: Just found the solution. I'll post it later as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cordova 4.0.x introduces some new features and one of them is domain whitelist. This is a plugin that is added to the plugin list and installed allong with the application being compiled. This plugin can be configured through the config.xml normally located at the root of the cordova project. In my case, because I was interested in change the application main activity domain i added the following to my config

```
<!-- A wildcard can be used to whitelist the entire network,
     over HTTP and HTTPS.
     *NOT RECOMMENDED* -->
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

[Plugin page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)
[Navigation-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#navigation-whitelist)